# Stuck in Fastboot mode after flashing custom ROM on Xiaomi Mi3W

Tags: unbricking, fastboot, miui

I flashed *MIUI fastboot ROM* on Xiaomi Mi3W since I had problem booting it. It was a old ROM but now nothing happens except it is stuck on fastboot mode. It doesn't even charge the battery. I tried re-flashing it but does not work.